# How to add custom theme in hosting server?

Tags: theme-development, installation, hosting

I made a custom theme on my local xampp server. Then I want to create my website. So I couldn't find a complete tutorial for installing custom theme to hosting server.

So I have theme files. I saw cPanel can install wordpress. After installing Wordpress to hosting server with cPanel, should I upload my theme folder to wordpress themes folder in hosting server?

Is that enough?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. You might also want to migrate the database, for which you can use a plugin like WP Migrate DB

Comment: @TuxedoMaskMusic, I thought you should know that there's an official guide here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-themes/#adding-new-themes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of two options, both will do give the same end result

1. zip your theme folder, using the cpanel navigate to themes folder, upload and extract. You should be able to see your theme in the wordpress admin dashboard.
2. zip your theme folder, in wordpress admin dashboard navigate to themes, choose new theme, than upload theme, upload your theme and activate.

If your theme work localy there shouldn't be any problems with the upload no matter what way you choose

Comment: Teşekkürler Süperman